# Generic Inquiry formula fields interpreted as text instead of numeric

Tags: acumatica

In a Generic Inquiry > Results Grid if we use a formula for the Data Field value the result is interpreted as being text. Something like...

```
=[ARTran.Qty] * IIf([ARTran.DrCr]='D', -1, 1)
```

...returns the desired value. However, when the Inquiry is run the filter options of the column are textual options ("Starts With") instead of the numeric options ("Is Greater Than"). Also when exported to Excel it is not possible to use the column in Excel formulas such as to SUM the column.

Is there any way to resolve this?

(The client makes extensive use of G.I.s with formula fields and writing them all as standard Inquiries is not practical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Schema Field to the ARTran.Qty field and that will display the result as numeric in the GI Result page and in Excel. You will need to set the Caption as well or it will use the caption of the Schema Field selected. 
[GI Result Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jroy.jpg)
[GI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRyn.jpg)